# Termos desconhecidos ponteiro em C

Tags: c, programação-estruturada

A primeira saida do printf esta saindo  um numero estranho, eu penso que %p seria o endereço do ponteiro nao seria, o resultado deu 0060FEFC?
na segunda saida *p + 2 = i + 2 eu entendo resultado deu 7, * *&p tambem nao entendi, achei que seria ponteiro para ponteiro mas nao entendi o e comercial e o resultado, saiu o valor do *p que é 5 parece que ignorou o resto, 3**p eu entendi que seria 3 * i tudo certo resultado deu 15, e * *&p+4 nao entendi o resultado nem a formulacao.. alguem poderia dar uma luz, obrigado

Edit1: me parece que a expressao dois asteristicos mais o e comercial mais a variavel é igual a asteristico mais variavel, estou certo disso?

Exercicio. Qual será a saída deste programa supondo que i ocupa o endereço 4094 na memória?

```
int main() {
int i=5, *p;
p = &i;
printf("%p %d %d %d %d \n", p,*p+2,**&p,3**p,**&p+4);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para cada caso:

#### p

O formato `%p` é utilizado para fazer uso de uma **formatação para exibição de um endereço em memória**. Um **ponteiro**, sendo a variável `p` neste caso, já retorna o endereço de memória para onde está apontando, por isso é passado na formatação mencionada retornando um valor parecido com o exemplo abaixo:

```
0x07ffe...
```

#### *p+2

Quando usa o operador `*` em um ponteiro que já havia sido declarado você está **acessando o conteúdo para onde ele está apontando**. Como o ponteiro no exemplo estava apontando para um valor de `5`, o resultado seria 7:

```
*p -> 5 -> 5 + 2 -> 7
```

#### **&p

O operador `&` retorna o endereço de memória de algum valor alocado; Usando isso em um ponteiro o valor de retorno é um **ponteiro para um ponteiro, sendo sua própria região em memória**. Para esclarecer as formas de acesso a um ponteiro:

- `p` -> Acessa a **região de memória para onde `p` está apontando**;
- `&p` -> Acessa a **região de memória do ponteiro**. Entende-se que o operador `&` já retorna um ponteiro para um valor, então usando o operador em `p` obtemos um ponteiro para uma região de memória que, por sua vez, aponta para algum valor;
- `*p` -> Acessa o **valor** para onde `p` está apontando; Neste caso, seria o valor `5`.

Ou seja, na hora de avaliar o valor para onde o mesmo está apontando, é necessário que utilize o operador `*` duas vezes. Considere a explicação:

- `&p` -> Retorna o endereço do ponteiro, ao usar o operador `&` um
  ponteiro é retornado, então temos um **ponteiro para um ponteiro**.
  O valor retornado seria o endereço de memória **do ponteiro**: `0x007fe...`;
- `*&p` -> Retorna o endereço para onde um ponteiro aponta. Equivalente a escrevermos apenas `p` nesse caso. Então o endereço para onde `p` aponta é
  retornado (o endereço da sua variável `i`): `0x007fc...`;
- `**&p` -> Como `&p` retorna o endereço para o ponteiro (`0x007fe`) e `*&p` nos dá acesso ao endereço para onde `p` aponta (`0x007fc...`), podemos concluir que usando o operador `*` novamente, obtemos o **valor** para onde `p` aponta, sendo `5`. Equivalente a escrever `*p`.

#### 3**p

Como já citado no exemplo com `*p+2`, o operador `*` vai fazer com que retorne o valor para onde o ponteiro está apontando. O operador do ponteiro é avaliado em `5` que é o valor para onde o ponteiro está apontando, resultando em uma operação de multiplicação (`int` x `int`):

```
*p -> 5 -> 3 * 5 -> 15
```

#### **&p+4

Os exemplos anteriores já deveriam deixar o caso final mais claro, usando os conceitos já vistos nos casos anteriores:

```
&p (ponteiro de um ponteiro, dois operadores * retornam seu valor) -> **&p -> 5 -> 5 + 4 -> 9
```

Comment: fala ruan, obrigado pela atencao, nao estou conseguindo entender essa parte **&p, eu consigo entender que &p é um endereço da variavel p, mas ai esses dois asteristicos eu nao entendi.. pelo que vejo falarem ponteiro para ponteiro sao dois asteristicos e a variavel, agora esse e comercial no meio nao to entendendo nada..

Comment: @CI2727 editei a pergunta complementando com uma explicação sobre como funcionam os operadores juntos e o que `&` retorna.

Comment: agora ficou perfeito, obrigado Ruan!