# Conversão inteiro para Binário | Estou com problemas para executar meu código, a função não aceitada o &

Tags: c, struct

Estou realizando uma atividade da faculdade (que alias já atrasei um dia para entregar), já finalizei o código mas não roda, e mesmo analisando e fazendo testes não consigo encontrar o erro.

Toda vez aparece o erro no parâmetro da função, não aceita o &, já retirei e tentei os ** mas mesmo assim não deu certo. Sou iniciante e estou bem perdida nesse exercício.

Poderiam me ajudar?  Segue atividade:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define tam 200



//.....Estrutura da Pilha.....
typedef struct{  
    int vetor[tam];  
    int topo;       
}pilha;


//............Funções.........
void iniciaP     (pilha *p);
void desempilhaP (pilha *p);
void imprimeP    (pilha *p);
void empilhaP    (pilha *p, int v);
void converterP  (pilha *p, int v);
int  tamanhoP    (pilha *p);
int  topoP       (pilha *p);
bool pilhaCheia  (pilha *p);
bool pilhaVazia  (pilha *p);


//......Inicia a Pilha.......
void iniciaP(pilha *p){ 
    p->topo = 0;    
}

//....Boleano Pilha Vazia....
bool pilhaVazia(pilha *p){
    return(p->topo == 0);
}

//....Boleano Pilha Cheia....
bool pilhaCheia(pilha *p){ 
    return(p->topo == tam);
}


//.....Empilha a Pilha.......
void empilhaP(pilha *p, int v){ 

    if(!pilhaCheia(p)){
        
        p->vetor[p->topo] = v;
        p->topo++;
        
    }else{
        
        printf("Ocorreu um erro, segue erro: \n PILHA LOTADA");
        
    }
}

//....Desempilha a Pilha......
void desempilhaP(pilha *p){
    
    if(!pilhaVazia(p)){
        
        p->topo--; 
        
    }else{
        printf("Ocorreu um erro, segue erro: \n PILHA VAZIA");
    }
    
}


//.......Tamanho Pilha.......
int tamanhoP(pilha *p){ 
    return(p->topo);
}


//......Imprime Pilha.......
void imprimeP(pilha *p){
    int i;
    
    printf("Valores da Pilha : {");
    for(i = 0; i < p->topo; i++){
        
        printf(" %d", p->vetor[i]);
        
    }
    printf(" }\n");
    
}

//.......Topo Pilha........
int topoP(pilha *p){ 

    int aux = p->vetor[p->topo-1];
    
    return(aux);
}

//....Converter Binario....
void converterP(pilha *p, int v){
    
    int conversao;
    int resto;
    
        
        resto = v;
        
        while(v != 1 && v != 0){
            
            conversao  = resto % 2;
            v = v / 2;
            empilhaP(p, conversao);

            resto   = v;
        }
        
        if(v == 1){
            
                empilhaP(p, 1);
        
        }else if (v == 0){
            
                empilhaP(p, 0);
                
        }
}


//..........MAIN........
int main(int argc , char const *argv[]){
    
    pilha  *Principal;
    int valor;
    int saida;
    int tamP;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    
    FILE *fileEntrada;
    FILE *fileSaida;
    
    fileEntrada = fopen("C:\\Users\\anaco\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\UTFPR\\ESTRUTURA_DE_DADOS\\Atv01\\entrada.txt","r");
    fileSaida   = fopen("C:\\Users\\anaco\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\UTFPR\\ESTRUTURA_DE_DADOS\\Atv01\\saida.txt","w");
    

    
    iniciaP(&Principal);
        
    if (fileEntrada == NULL) { 
    
        printf("Nao deu para abrir o arquivo de entrada\n");
        
    }else{
        
        for (i = 0; i < tam; i++){
            
            fscanf(fileEntrada, "%d" , &valor);
            
            empilhaP(&Principal, valor);
            
                if (feof (fileEntrada) ){
                    
                break;
                 
                }
            }
        }

    tamP = topoP(&Principal);
    printf("Tamanho da pilha : %d", tamP);
    
    imprimeP(&Principal);
    

    
    fclose(fileEntrada);
    fclose(fileSaida);
    
    return 0;
}
```

erro :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Há alguns problemas no seu código e no resultado esperado, mas responderei apenas a pergunta feita:

> [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'iniciaP' from incompatible pointer type

Recomendo que leia [este post sobre ponteiros e endereços de memória em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/494139/termos-desconhecidos-ponteiro-em-c/494140#494140).

O que aconteceu na declaração da sua pilha na função `main`:

```
pilha *Principal;
```

Isso significa que você está declarando **um ponteiro**. Um ponteiro é apenas um valor que representa um endereço na memória (o começo do endereço no caso de um vetor, por exemplo).

Da forma que está atualmente, o ponteiro é apenas uma declaração **mas não aponta para lugar algum**. A variável foi criada para guardar um valor que representa uma região de memória (endereço de memória) mas não tem nada nela.

Utilizando como exemplo as chamadas para a função `empilhaP`, segue duas formas diferentes de corrigir o problema: deixar o valor no ["monte" (ou heap)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap) ou na [pilha de chamada (call stack)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilha_de_chamada).

No "monte", você vai precisar do arquivo `<stdlib.h>` para importar a função [`malloc`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=functions-malloc-reserve-storage-block) e reservar memória para o seu `struct`:

```
// No começo do arquivo: #include <stdlib.h>
// A função "malloc" recebe um único argumento que é o tamanho da região de memória que deseja em bytes.
// Para resgatarmos o tamanho que sua estrutura representa, usamos a função "sizeof".
pilha *Principal = malloc(sizeof(pilha));

// Verifique se foi possível alocar memória suficiente para representar a estrutura no seu programa. 
// A função "malloc" retorna NULL caso não consiga alocar a memória que pediu.
if (Principal != NULL) {
    // ... continue as operações
}
```

E ao final do uso, você deve liberar a memória usada utilizando a função [`free`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=functions-free-free-block-storage), que recebe um ponteiro que aponta para a região que pediu a liberação de memória com `malloc` como argumento:

```
free(Principal);
```

Caso prefira usar a pilha e não alocar memória manualmente (pois terá que ser liberada ao finalizar seu uso) você pode declarar sua variável como:

```
pilha Principal;
```

Perceba a ausência do `*` e de qualquer atribuição. Isso significa que sua variável não é mais um ponteiro para uma estrutura e sim uma estrutura na pilha de chamada.

Ao chamar a função da forma que está fazendo após ter criado um ponteiro:

```
empilhaP(&Principal, 2);
```

Você está passando **um ponteiro para um ponteiro**. Quando usamos `&`, dizemos ao compilador que o valor que seguir a partir do caractere é um endereço para o mesmo. Ou seja, tendo uma variável declarada como:

```
int numero = 1;
```

E fizermos a mesma coisa que fez nas chamadas na função `main` (usar `&`):

```
int *ptr = &numero;
```

A variável `ptr` **não contém o valor da variável `numero` copiado nela, mas o endereço de memória onde o valor da variável `numero` está guardado**.

Para passar o endereço da sua estrutura corretamente ainda usando um ponteiro, você pode passá-lo diretamente:

```
empilhaP(Principal, 2);
```

Ou criar uma variável na pilha de chamada (sem o `*`) e passar o endereço dele:

```
empilhaP(&Principal, 2);
```

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigada. Ajudou muito.